# Commercial solvers for non-convex optimization problems

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

Is there any recommended commercial non-convex solver for bilinear equality constraints? E.g.,

$$ \begin{aligned} x_1 x_2 &= x_3 \\ x_1 x_3 &= x_4 \\ &\vdots \\
x_1 x_n &= x_{n+1} \end{aligned} $$

Non-commercial solver IPOPT can solve it efficiently, and I would like to try some commercial solvers and comparing them.

Comment: Why not use Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: Could you explain more? I didn't get your point..... thanks

Comment: What kind of objective function do you have?  Please provide an example.  You might consider using Lagrange multipliers, one multiplier per equality constraint. It would also be nice to know what motivated this question.  Where do these constraints come from?

Comment: I tried to estimate the decay parameter in Exponentially Weighted Moving Average (EWMA) model: $y_{t} = \sum_{k=1}^K \frac{\lambda^k}{\sum_{j=1}^K \lambda^j } y_{t - k} + e_t $, where $K<N$. $x_1 = \lambda$, $x_{k>1} = \frac{\lambda^k}{\sum_{j=1}^K \lambda^j } $

Comment: The objective function is the standard quadratic function  for linear least squares and $\lambda^K \neq 0$

Comment: If the objective and constraints are quadratic, why not use symbolic methods instead?  Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3784932/339790)

Comment: Thank you, I have a look and test the speed, BTW, the ipopt can solve it within 0.5 sec with K = 500, N = 5000.